# Colourful puzzle

Tags: mathematics, visual, calculation-puzzle

Can you find appropriate number to complete this puzzle? :D Also, don't forget to consider colors given to each grid. They will help you a lot to find final answer.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 84

Reasoning

> In each of the sets of two coloured boxes read a number bottom to top
>  PINK=84, GREEN = 52, ROYAL BLUE = 97
>  Then subtract the number directly below in LIGHT BLUE to get the number directly below that in GREY, that is
>  84 - 5 = 79
>  52 - 7 = 45
>  97 - 13 = **84**

Comment: Yes you are right. :)